# Flash play() processed immediately?

Tags: actionscript, flash, playing

Does the `play()` function in Flash:

1. move the playhead of the MovieClip to the next frame -- as soon as `play()` is called
2. change the MovieClip's state to "playing" -- actually move MovieClip to next frame, when movie moves to next frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In normal circumstances it would be option 2. However, it is possible to have the frame re-drawn immediately. There is a catch though, you can only do this within mouse move and timer interval handlers. In AS3 have a look at the [MouseEvent.updateAfterEvent](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html) and the [TimerEvent.updateAfterEvent](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/TimerEvent.html) methods. In AS 2 there is a global [updateAfterEvent](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/00001233.html) function you can call with the same restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

I think its **2.** change the MovieClip's state to "playing"

Comment: I agree, everything that's on the current frame will still be available until it that frame "ends" and the next one is displayed.